# Get the text of the selected radio button

Tags: jquery

How can I get which radio is selected via jQuery?

I have two radio buttons and want to post the text of the selected one, how can I get the text with jQuery?

I know how to get the value of the selected radio button :

```js
    $('[name="topping"]:checked').val()
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Would you like extra topping?</label>
  <input type="radio" value="y" name="topping" id="toppingy"/><label for="toppingy"
                                                                     class="sidelabel">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" value="n" name="topping" id="toppingn"/><label for="toppingn" class="sidelabel">No</label>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work :

```js
    $('[name="topping"]:checked').text()
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: share your html because input element does not have text... it might be present in an adjacent element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `+` selector at this context,

```
$('[name="topping"]:checked + label').text();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g1sb9tsk/)

Answer (score 0):

The element checkbox doesn't have any text - You could solve it via workareound - as a title tag for example - or a `<span>` after your radio.

HTML:

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" title="testname" name="testme"><br>
<input class="radio" type="radio" title="testname2" name="testme">
```

JQ:

```
$('.radio').on('change', function(){
    var names = $(this).attr('title');
    alert(names);
});
```

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/bybz8xue/

Edit: Working example with your code (**Added a class**):

```
$('.topping').on('change', function(){
    var names = $(this).next('label').text();
    alert(names);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bybz8xue/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've amended your HTML, you have a group of related options so I've wrapped the radio-inputs in a `<fieldset>` and used the `<legend>` element to provide a relevant indication of what the options are related to (a `<label>` is to associate a specific text with a specific form-element (`<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`) not a generic label/heading for a group. That said, I'd suggest:

```
// selecting the <input> elements of 'type="radio"',
// using on() to bind a change-event handler:
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  // this is the newly-checked radio <input>,
  // here we get the text of the next-element:
  var text = this.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  console.log(text);
});
```

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  var text = this.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Would you like extra topping?</legend>
  <input type="radio" value="y" name="topping" id="toppingy" />
  <label for="toppingy" class="sidelabel">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" value="n" name="topping" id="toppingn" />
  <label for="toppingn" class="sidelabel">No</label>
</fieldset>
```

Alternatively, in compliant browsers, we can abstract away from a specific DOM structure, and use the `labels` property, which returns a NodeList of `<label>` elements related to the specific element:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  // getting NodeList containing the related <label> elements:
  var relatedLabels = this.labels,
      // if there are any labels associated, we get the text
      // of the first <label>, otherwise we use an empty string:
      text = this.labels.length ? this.labels[0].textContent : '';
  console.log(text);
});
```

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  var relatedLabels = this.labels,
      text = this.labels.length ? this.labels[0].textContent : '';
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Would you like extra topping?</legend>
  <input type="radio" value="y" name="topping" id="toppingy" />
  <label for="toppingy" class="sidelabel">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" value="n" name="topping" id="toppingn" />
  <label for="toppingn" class="sidelabel">No</label>
</fieldset>
```